# Why does Zend Studio fail to bring up auto-complete menu on objects, when I use PHP arrays?

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete, zend-studio, typing

I seem to be having some trouble with my IDE or maybe my code.  My IDE (ZendStudio 11 built on Eclipse) is not giving me auto-suggest methods on object when I put that object into a PHP native array construct.

As you will see below, auto-suggest work for things that do not have `$this->` (object accessor) and do not have `[$index]` (array accessor), but *fail* to work after those accessors are present.

**Consider the Code below**

See comments for trouble areas

```php
namespace Name\Space;

class PointArrayManager
{

    private $points;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $point = new Point();
        $point-> //brings up auto-complete for Point()

        $points[0] = new Point();
        $points[0]-> //brings up auto-complete for Point()

        $this->points[0] = new Point();
        $this->points[0]-> //FAILS to bring up auto-complete 
    }
}
```

What causes this issue and can I improve my code to have autosuggest anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE has no way of knowing that your `$points` property is an array of Point objects. You will have to give it some help.

The way to do this is to comment your code, at the very least you will need to comment the declaration of the `$points` variable like this:-

```
/** @var Point[] $points */
private $points;
```

I don't use Zend Studio, but this works in PHPStorm, so I imagine it does in Zend Studio too.

Commenting your code like this is good practice and helps your IDE to know what you mean. It also helps with generation documentation. Most PHP IDE's use PHPDocumentor for comments, so the manual there is worth a read.

http://www.phpdoc.org/

Comment: thanks.  even though there was autosuggest after `@var`, the code inside `__construct` still did not bring up autosuggest.   But thanks.  I am hoping newer versions will have that implemented

Comment: Shell out for phpstorm, you won't regret it. You can try it free for 30 days, so it's worth giving it a shot.